# Explanation of Code : retrieve item from Array using FirstorDefault()

Tags: c#, .net, arrays, linq

Lets say I have some items in an array

```
Product[] myProducts = new Product[]
{
    new Product { ID = 1, name = "Ketchup1", category = "Sauces", price = 200.00m },
    new Product { ID = 2, name = "Ketchup2", category = "Sauces", price = 200.00m },
    new Product { ID = 3, name = "Ketchup3", category = "Sauces", price = 200.00m }
};
```

Then lets say I try to retrieve using this method

```
public Product GetProductById(int id)
{
    var product = products.FirstOrDefault((p) => p.Id == id);
    if (product == null)
    {
        throw new HttpResponseException(HttpStatusCode.NotFound);
    }
    return product;
}
```

I have read what it does but I don't get what is happening here:

```
FirstorDefault(p => p.Id == id);
```

Comment: See: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb311046.aspx

Comment: Its creating a temp variable of type Product and then comparing its `Id` property to the given value

Comment: it is a lambda expression, [check it](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/bb397687.aspx)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`FirstOrDefault(predicate)` iterates over collection and returns first element that matches the predicate. In your example it will be the first element with `p.Id == id`. When there is no value that matched the predicate default value is returned (`null` for all referece types).

`(p) => p.Id == id` is a [lambda expression](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397687.aspx) that matches `Func<Product, bool>` - it takes one parameter of type `Product` (it's named `p`) and returns `bool` value.

**`FirstOrDefault`** probably looks really similar to it's [eduLINQ equivalent](http://msmvps.com/blogs/jon_skeet/archive/2010/12/29/reimplementing-linq-to-objects-part-11-first-single-last-and-the-ordefault-versions.aspx):

```
public static TSource FirstOrDefault<TSource>( 
    this IEnumerable<TSource> source, 
    Func<TSource, bool> predicate) 
{ 
    // Argument validation elided 
    foreach (TSource item in source) 
    { 
        if (predicate(item)) 
        { 
            return item; 
        } 
    } 
    return default(TSource); 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

this the condition than needs to be satisfied.

```
(p) => p.Id == id
```

is lambda function, which given argument p returns p.Id == id

It's called on each element until it's true.

Thus, `product` will be the first element for which the Id matches the given id or null if there isn't such